# Customizing Struts Displaytag table properties

Tags: html, struts2, displaytag

I have knowledge on how to customize the display data using Struts2 displaytag:table and decorator.

But I need to customize the table columns (tr style)

```
public String getWorkFlow() {
    WorkOrderDO currentWorkOrder = (WorkOrderDO) getCurrentRowObject();
    String output = null;
    if (currentWorkOrder.getChildId() == 0) {
        if (!currentWorkOrder.isWorkFlowRetrieved()) {
            output = "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Work Flow' id=" + currentWorkOrder.getMoveWorkOrderId() + " onclick = 'changeWorkOrder(this);return false;'/>";
        } else {
            output = "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Work Flow' id=" + currentWorkOrder.getMoveWorkOrderId() + " onclick = 'changeWorkOrder(this);return false;' disabled/>";
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

from above method in decorator class, we can customize the data look and feel.

But my question is, if `currentWorkOrder.isWorkFlowRetrieved() == true`, I want to highlight the entire column (tr) in the table in the display page with style property

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using style attribute in the display:column tag

for eg

I hope this works for you.

Comment: display:column title="Name" style="align:left;" property="name"